# Node-Addon-Api Pass Array As Function Argument

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I am trying to create a basic native node addon where a javascript array is passed from node and then processed in c++. The problem is I cannot figure out how to correctly pass the array. I can instantiate the array without issue but assigning it using info[0].as throws errors.

My c++ code is

```
#include <napi.h>

using namespace Napi;
using namespace std;

Value Add(const CallbackInfo& info) 
{
  Env env = info.Env();


  Array result = Napi::Array::New(env);
  Array a = info[0].As<Array>;

  double arg1 = info[1].As<Number>().DoubleValue();
  Number num = Napi::Number::New(env, 2 + arg1);

  return num;
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
../cppsrc/main.cpp: In function ‘Napi::Value Add(const Napi::CallbackInfo&)’:
../cppsrc/main.cpp:12:21: error: conversion from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to non-scalar type ‘Napi::Array’ requested
   Array a = info[0].As<Array>;
             ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

What is the correct way to pass an array to c++? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
void runSetPropertyAsyncWorker(const CallbackInfo& info) 
{
    std::string path = info[0].As<Napi::String>();
    int property = info[1].As<Number>();
    int dataSize = info[2].As<Number>();
    Array b = info[3].As<Array>();
    for(int i = 0; i<b.Length(); i++)
    {
      Napi::Value v = b[i];
      if (v.IsNumber())
      {
        int value = (int)v.As<Napi::Number>();
        ...
        ...
      }
    }

    ...
    ...

    Function callback = info[4].As<Function>();
    AsyncWorker* asyncWorker = new SetPropertyAsyncWorker(callback, ...);
    asyncWorker->Queue();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Napi::Object`. `Napi::Array` is actually inherited from `Napi::Object`.

You could replace the code `Array a = info[0].As<Array>;` with `Array a = info[0].ToObject();`.

You can then access the data members via Value 
`operator[] (uint32_t index) const`

**Source**: https://nodejs.github.io/node-addon-api/class_napi_1_1_object.html

**Edit**: Bonus feature, if an argument that is not an object is passed, this will automatically trigger an `Error: Object Expected`.

Answer (score 1):

error code here:

```cpp
Array a = info[0].As<Array>;
```

which should be

```cpp
Array a = info[0].As<Array>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a solution to the actual question of interacting with the Javascript object directly with node-addon-api. The Solution that I chose to go with is JSON.stringify any arrays or objects and then parse then in c++ is a library called [rapid json](https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson). This proves to be the only way to interface with javascript objects that i've been able to find

Comment: That is not true. Plus, it slows down the code dramatically because you will have to parse the JSON in c++. It is also not very convenient in JavaScript.

Comment: I understand it was not an ideal solution but it was the best i could come up with at the time. With the size of the data that I was working with it was not really a speed concern. Also rapid JSON is a very fast c++ json library.